# Views exposed filter selection

Tags: views

I want to use view to show car parts.

I have 2 exposed fields (car manufacturer and car part like doors light etc)
The view work nice but what i want is to have a way for example when user click at the first list (example Audi) to show if there is any part in the another list for parts.

Ex.
In Audi i have only Doors and not lights
When user select from first list Audi the list for part only show Doors.

So if Audi only have nodes for Doors will show in second exposed filter only the Doors option.

Drupal 7 views 3

Comment: What's the underlying structure for all of this. Content types? taxonomies? Also, how are car manufacturers related to car parts? entity reference?

Comment: I use 2 fields from a Content type Product. One list for Manufacture and another for part list.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing it sounds like you need Faceted search. I'm not sure if Views filters can give you the functionality you're looking for.

Have a look at the Search Api module, it provides faceted search widgets which behave the way you described.

https://drupal.org/project/search_api

Answer (score 0):

[Reference field option limit](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) is fine to acomplish this. You want to create a term reference field in vocabulary «parts» referencing terms in vocabulary «manufacturers». I did explain it detailed [in an issue](https://drupal.org/node/1532124).

Also for views integration this module needs a patch you can find [here](https://drupal.org/node/2035157).